Can't encounter 'Villain' in text based game
Extreme python newbie and currently taking a python class. Trying to do an adventure text game. I've got the directions and retrieving items part correctly but my if in inventory doesn't run and still adds item and I can't seem to encounter my "villain" when I enter that room.
This is what I have to grab items:
    if 'item' in inventory:
        print('You already have the ', rooms[current_room]['item'])
        player_move = input('Enter your move: ')
        action = player_move.title().split()
        print('-------------------')
    elif action[1] == rooms[current_room]['item'] and 'item' not in inventory:
        inventory.append(action[1])
        print(rooms[current_room]['item'], 'retrieved')
        player_move = input('Enter your move: ')
        action = player_move.title().split()
        print('-------------------')

I currently have this for the Villain but it never triggers
    if 'Villain' in rooms[current_room].keys():
        if len(inventory) < 6:
             print("You got caught before you could complete your mission! :(")
             break

        else:
             print("You successfully infiltrated the company!")
             break

Instead it just acts like I entered another room, shows my inventory, and asks for my next move

You shared two snippets of code, but neither shows why your rooms data structure would contain a 'Villain' key. You'll have to share more code. If you don't want to share the whole thing, or feel that it is too much to put here, select those parts of the code that you feel should make 'encountering the villain' work.

'item' in inventory, and similar checks, are almost certainly not what you want - that would only be true if you had picked up an item literally named "item".

Also, try print(rooms[current_room]) just before if 'Villain'... check, to see whether it contains what you think it contains. If not, work backwards, seeing why it is like this and not like that.

Thanks everyone I figured it out, see the answer I posted for the final codes I used.

In my rooms dictionary only one room had a key value of 'Villain' which is why I used that to identify where the villain was.

the item in inventory WAS incorrect - I had verify it was in my current room first, then assigned it a variable to check if it was in my inventory

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I finally got it to work!
For the inventory issue I added another if statement beforehand to check if the item was in the room then assigned that item a variable to check if it was in inventory. This is the final code I used:
#If item is already in player's inventory do not add again and let them know
if 'item' in rooms[current_room].keys():
    nearby_item = rooms[current_room]['item']
    if nearby_item in inventory:
    print('You already have a', rooms[current_room]['item'])
    line_break()
    
#If item not in inventory append to inventory list
elif action[1] == rooms[current_room]['item'] and 'item' not in inventory:
    inventory.append(action[1])
    #confirm item is retrieved
    print(rooms[current_room]['item'], 'retrieved')
    line_break()

For my Villain interaction I had to move the Villain interaction to the start of the loop - I originally had it outside just before the loop started.
Also for clarification purposes I figured out where to add the
player_move = input('Enter your move: ').title()
action = player_move.split()

so that I didn't have to keep repeating it. And switched the .title to the input because it wasn't catching my exit clause. I then created a function for my print('-------------------') to make the main function look cleaner.
